# What if an access control is applied to friends?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I'm reading C++11 Standard (N3092).

*11-4 Member access control* says

> Access control is applied uniformly to all names, whether the names are referred to from declarations or expressions. [ Note: **access control applies to names nominated by friend declarations** (11.4) and using- declarations (7.3.3). — end note ]

*11.4-9 Friends* says

> A name nominated by a friend declaration shall be accessible in the scope of the class containing the friend declaration. **The meaning of the friend declaration is the same whether the friend declaration appears in the private, protected or public (9.2) portion of the class member-specification.**

With my poor English skill, it seems these two excerpts aren't consistent. What if an access control is applied to `friend`s, as indicated in the first excerpt? Could anyone please give me a concrete example code?

---

The first excerpt also says about `using`-declarations. That can be confirmed via the code below. So you can say "access control is certainly applied to using-declarations." But I have no idea how to write a code to see the behavior of access-controled `friend` functions.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

class B {
    public:
        void f() { cout << "B::f()\n"; }
        void f(int) { cout << "B::f(int)\n"; }
};

class D : public B {
    public:
        using B::f; //`using` declaration in `public` context
        void f() { cout << "D::f()\n"; }
};

class D2 : public B {
    using B::f; //`using` declaration in `private` context
    public:
        void f() { cout << "D2::f()\n"; }
};

int main() {

    D d;
    d.f(); //=> "D::f()"
    d.f(0); //=> "B::f(int)"

    D2 d2;
    d2.f(); //=> "D2::f()"
    d2.f(0); //=> "error: ‘void B::f(int)’ is inaccessible within this context"

}
```

As the code above, if I write

```
public:
    friend void some_func() { }
```

, is access control applied to the name `some_func`? How?

Comment: Α friend function is the same as a member function except that it doesn't automatically get a `this` pointer and, therefore, needs an object in order to access the members. The protection is about *which* members are accessible, given the `this` pointer which a member automatically has.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis So there can exist a friend function which can access *a part of* class members?

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis — a member function of another class can be a friend. Friendship is simply about allowing access.

Comment: @ynn — no; a friend has access to all members.

Comment: @PeteBecker So what does it mean by "The protection is about which members are accessible"?

Comment: @ynn — I don’t know where that quote came from. It’s sloppy.

Comment: @ynn - I agree with Pete Becker that those quotes are sloppily worded (the C++ standards and drafts aren't perfect). My interpretation of the first is "all friends of a class must be accessible to that class" (e.g.  if `B` has a private member function named `f()` and `B` does not declare `A` as a friend, then `A` cannot declare `B::f()` as a friend).  My interpretation of the second quote is "the friend declaration has the same effect whether it appears in a public, protected, or private section of the class definition".    If my interpretations are correct, the two quotes are unrelated.

Comment: @Peter Thank you for your perfect explanation. I do agree with you interpretation. It's also consistent with the (un-bolded) first sentence of the second excerpt. I misunderstood the first excerpt in a way that "if you write `private: int x`, `private` access control is applied to name `x`" (but *literally*, is my interpretation bad? I think it's ambiguous as a language though your interpretation is right *semantically*). Anyway, my question has been solved. Thank you again.

Comment: @ynn Ah, no. My original interpretation is even literally wrong because the first excerpt says "whether the names are **referred to from** declarations **or expression.**".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it seems these two excerpts aren't consistent

They are consistent, but they don't have to be. Anything inside a `[note: ]` block is non-normative text. It is there to summarize something for human purposes or to provide clarifying examples, but it is not used to define the actual behavior of the language. So the only excerpt that actually matters is the second one.

The bolded text in first excerpt is talking about the *content* of the friend declaration. If you have two classes, `A` and `B`, and you want to make a specific member of `B` a friend of `A`, what the bolded text is saying is that the specific member you name must already be accessible by `A`. That is, this is illegal:

```
class B
{
private:
  void SomeMember();
};

class A
{
private:
  friend void B::SomeMember(); //`SomeMember` is not accessible to `A`, so ill-formed.
};
```

`B` would have to make itself a friend of `A`, so that `A` could name its private members.

The bolded text in the second excerpt merely says that the location where the `friend` declaration happens in a class doesn't matter. It doesn't matter if the `friend` declaration is public, private, or whatever. That is, all of the following mean the same thing:

```
class B;

class A1
{
public:
  friend class B;
};

class A2
{
protected:
  friend class B;
};

class A3
{
private:
  friend class B;
};
```

So the two bolded excerpts have nothing to do with one another.

Now, the unbolded part of the second except actually says in normative language what the notation in the first excerpt says. Namely, names specified in a `friend` declaration have to be accessible.

> if I write <...> is access control applied to the name `some_func`? How?

It's fine. `friend` *definitions* always define non-member functions. As such, they're not in the scope of a class, so they are de-facto `public`. And therefore accessible.